# Adding a vline in ggplot2 using time

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am having some problems adding a vertical line to a gplot2 graph.

My example dataframe is listed below.

```
set.seed(1234)
df <- data.frame(Date=seq(as.POSIXct("05:00", format="%H:%M"), 
                          as.POSIXct("23:00", format="%H:%M"), by="hours"))
df$Counts <- sample(19)
df <- df[-c(4,7,17,18),]

# generate the groups automatically and plot
idx <- c(1, diff(df$Date))
i2 <- c(1,which(idx != 1), nrow(df)+1)
df$grp <- rep(1:length(diff(i2)), diff(i2))
g <- ggplot(df, aes(x=Date, y=Counts)) + geom_line(aes(group = grp)) + 
  geom_point()
```

There seems to be quite a lot of discussion on stack overflow and the web generally about using vlines on timeseries.  I have had a go at rectifying my code but I am not having much luck so far.

Say for example I want a vertical line at 2 pm on the 21st.

```
g1 <- g + geom_vline(xintercept=as.numeric(as.Date("2013-02-21 14:00:00")))
```

Could anyone advise me how I might get this to work?

Comment: `as.Date` retains just the date part, not `%H:%M:%S` info.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to replace `as.Date()` with `as.POSIXct()` because you also need time not just date (function `as.Date()` represents only date part).

```
g + geom_vline(xintercept=as.numeric(as.POSIXct("2013-02-21 14:00:00")))
```

You can see the difference by looking on those two cases:

```
 as.Date("2013-02-21 14:00:00")
[1] "2013-02-21"

 as.POSIXct("2013-02-21 14:00:00")
[1] "2013-02-21 14:00:00 EET"
```

Comment: many thanks.  Is there anyway I can make this more generic and get rid of the date on the vline command?  I am running this script for multiple files with different days so just want to add a time for the vline.  Is this possible?

Comment: @KT_1 The date in geom_vline() is necessary as it is calculated as origin from 01.01.1970. when converted to numeric.